# BigQuery, using partition key and cluster key together to reduce query size - clustering not helping?

Tags: google-bigquery, partitioning

We have a BigQuery table with fields `competitionId`, `conferenceId`, `name`, `age`, `desc`, etc and we are trying to improve the performance (reduce bytes scanned) of our queries. We are using DBT and create a partitioned & clustered table as such:

```
{{ config(
    materialized = 'table',
    cluster_by = ['conferenceId'],
    partition_by = {
      "field": "competitionId",
      "data_type": "int64",
      "range": {
        "start": 0,
        "end": 9,
        "interval": 1
      }
    }
)}}
```

There are 9 major competitionIds, ranging from 1-9, and we use an integer partition on the `competitionId` field. `conferenceId` is also an integer field, ranging from 0-110, and we set `conferenceId` as a cluster field. Screenshot below from BigQuery showing the table successfully created as partitioned and clustered:

[image]

With the table created, we've got the following 3 queries:

**Scan entire table - 373MB**
[image]

**Scan with competitionId partition - 58MB (partition working!)**
[image]

**Scan with both IDs - 58MB (cluster key conferenceId not helping...)**
[image]

I had expected the query size to get much smaller when querying on both the partition key and cluster key, however adding `conferenceId` to the query did not reduce the bytes scanned at all... How can we update this such that our queries only scan over the specific `competitionId + conferenceId` for our query?

**Edit:** in this example - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wapi0aR4BZE - they are able to combine the partition key and cluster key to dramatically reduce the size of the query vs. using the partition key alone.

Comment: Did you run the query? Clustering is applied after query plan. So effectively you need to run the query and compare the reported bytes billed, and not the estimator. Also partitioning combined with clustering works on large datasets. I might be too small dataset here.

Comment: @Pentium10 I did run the query and the reported bytes was the same 58MB for both the 2nd and 3rd queries. I will try to create a reproducible example using a table created from BQ public datasets.

Comment: The tables we are working with are in the range of 500MB - 20GB, are these too small? We query many tables daily and 100 - 200 of these queries each day has shot us past the free tier of BigQuery. Partitioning on a single key has helped, but incorporating clustered tables seems like it could help a whole lot more.

Comment: It seems I am not able to CREATE TABLE from bigquery public datasets into my own project with PARTITION and CLUSTER added to the table, invalid permission. Is it not possible to dupe BQ public dataset tables into other projects? Any other recommendations on creating a large-scale reproducible example for this question?

Comment: AFAIK "too small" dataset is not documented. But from experience, a single shard or cluster should be 4GB to be effective. So if you expect 100 shards, that's 400GB table. Check out this article, it has the examples you need. https://hoffa.medium.com/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b

Comment: @Pentium10 okay thanks. so a 10GB table with 50 partitions of 200MB each may not benefit at all from additional clustering within the 50 partitions? 500MB - 20GB with 50-100 partitions is size / partitioning for most of our tables currently. Seems like clustering may not help further.

Comment: You can use, and it's recommended to use clustering, but you might not see it effective on smaller datasets. But it's still recommended, as query optimizer can be updated under the hood, and suddenly you can see effective.